# Android custom List SimpleAdapter - chose row icon

Tags: java, android, listadapter

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/line_a"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/line_b"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
    SimpleAdapter sa;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String,String> item;

    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put( "line1", ListData[i][0]);
        item.put( "line2", ListData[i][1]);
        item.put( "type", ListData[i][2]);
        list.add( item );
    }

    sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.two_lines_list,
            new String[] { "line1","line2" },
            new int[] {R.id.line_a, R.id.line_b});
                         // can you add the setImageView here? If yes, how?
    setListAdapter( sa );
}
```

How can I make the icon to get an image from res/drawable... depending on the type (ListData[i][2] inserted in the HashMap)? eg. if the type is "1" set icon1.png at the beginning of the 2-line-row

Answer (score 0):

You should override `SimpleAdapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method, and get the list item with the current position(the first param in that method), then check the value set set the icon you want.

NOTE: you' d better use **ViewHolder** pattern in the `getView` method for performance.